# Wrong UI orientation on UIImagePickerController when entering camera first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I have wrong UI orientation on UIImagePickerController when entering camera first time on iPad. Device in landscape but UIImagePickerController in portrait.

[That how it's looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex6NH.jpg)

After device rotation everything is ok - UIImagePickerController gets correct UI orientation.

I have

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; 
}
```

and

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: What `Supported interface orientations` are set in **Info.plist** ?

Comment: @IgorKulagin as I sad after device rotation everything is ok and works as expected. So there is 4 supported interface orientations in Info.plist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer.

The presenting controller(UIViewController) has a property called modalPresentationStyle and it was set as `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`.
To resolve my problem I just set it as `UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen`.

```
presentingController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
```

Thats all.